# Failed to deploy Spring and MySQL application using Docker

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect a Spring server to a Mysql database, both running in different containers, and I got this error:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:162) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.<init>(ConnectionUrlParser.java:136) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.parseConnectionString(ConnectionUrlParser.java:118) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.getConnectionUrlInstance(ConnectionUrl.java:197) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:196) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar!/:8.0.17]
        ... 53 common frames omitted
```

For the Mysql container I am using the latest image from dockerhub. 
I'm guessing that the ip address of the mysql container i'm trying to connect to is wrong, but I don't know how to obtain the correct address.

I am starting the mysql container via:

```
docker run -p 3036:3036 --name mysql-container -d mysql
```

application.properties in the Spring project:

```
database.ip = ${MYSQL_IP:mysql-container}
database.port = ${MYSQL_PORT:3306}
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${database.ip}:${database.port}/${database.name}
```

backend container:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name backend_container --link mysql-container:mysql -d backend_container
```

I didn't use Docker until now, so sorry if it is a trivial/boring question.

I would appreciate some help! :)

Comment: The code above works when the server runs on the host machine and not in the container (and mysql in container), but when both in container, still the same error.

Comment: So when you try to run it from docker, it throws error.

Answer (score 1):

As I found out, the problem was that the 2 containers were not on the same docker network.

When I started them with docker-compose using a docker-compose.yml, the 2 containers were started on the same default network, so that the spring container could connect to the mysql container ip address.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  mysql-container:
    container_name: mysql-container
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db_name
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
  spring_app_container:
    container_name: spring_app_container
    image: spring_app
    depends_on:
      - mysql-container
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=mysql-container
      - DATABASE_USER=root
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
      - DATABASE_NAME=db_name
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

Comment: Worked for me, I was just missing the spring app environment section.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand why the database was containerized. Generally speaking, there's no reason for that.

Check if your database host has port-forwarding, i.e. port 3036 on the database host should be mapped to a URL or a global IP address. Check out [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) so that you're unblocked, but there's a "proper" way to do this that's usually specific to your cloud provider.

Edit: There's also a typo in the code you posted. Your `docker run` command uses port 3036, but your Spring code contains `database.port = ${MYSQL_PORT:3306}`. Can't tell whether that's just a typo on here or in your actual code, but that's also possibly there.